# Sitecore and SolrCloud switch on rebuild

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8, solrcloud

As you may already know that Sitecore, configured to work with SolrCloud, does not support index switch on rebuild. Is there a way to achieve this with version 4.10.3 of Solr and Sitecore 8.0?

We found a link - https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.449298 - but this has only been tested from version 5.2.1 to 5.5.1. Does anyone have any experience implementing this for version 4.10.3? Any issues that we may need to be aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This patch was created as the old `SwitchOnRebuild` used the Solr Core switching API which is now deprecated in version 5.* and above. It was not recommended when running in SolrCloud mode due to an issue with Zookeeper.

This code uses the Solr 'collections' API (`/solr/admin/collections?action=LIST`) instead , you would need to check if this API is available for Solr 4.10 (I think it is but I'm not 100% sure)

You would then just need to ignore the parts about the `schemaFactory` as that is Solr 5.* specific.

Note that this patch relies on the `405677` patch to be applied too.

Comment: Are you saying that we should not use this patch with Sitecore 8 and Solr 4.10.3 with SolrCloud?

I went to http://[solrdomain]/solr/admin/collections and got a 404 response. I also checked to see if there were any handlers I needed to enable for the collections API but I did not find anything.

Comment: I was saying if you can access the collections API then it would probably work. Try `/solr/admin/collections?action=LIST`